# how to move images in openGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have developed some how 5 iphone application, but now there is one game, and still I haven't any idea except word open GL ES, I read it a bit but I need some explanation and guidance for developing it.

The theme of game is like "there are many objects are moving from down to upside and i have to pick them and drag in boxes according to their color"

can anyone help me for showing proper way how to achieve, the study sources and other material,,

Thanks in Advance,,,

Comment: Before delving into OpenGL you should really think, if it is neccessary for your case and if your willing to learn it. Or we end up with another iGuy that doesn't undestand any computer graphics or even his own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer but why don't you use an objective-c wrapper like cocos2d. That would speed up the things.

Comment: how, any simple example, do you have

Comment: here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/, you can find there sample code, a good supporting forum and the entire documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer either, but are you sure you need OpenGL ES for that?

If your game is simple enough, you can use only custom UIViews. That would be much easier, especially to handle touch interactions.

Comment: but don't you think that it will be heavy, it is necessory but I think there will be too many objects so will it be workable without openGL ES?

Comment: can u guide me with a simple example? because I can do but I might sure that it will be heavy and client won't happy with that

Comment: Well, without any specs for your game, I can't tell if it's gonna be too many. There are many ways to implement good stuff using only UIViews, you can look at custom drawing using 'drawRect:' if needed.